# JSF Ajax's listener is reached before the event itslef

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

i'm trying to figure out the ajax's tag 'listener' property, and from what i read [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/10/09/jsf-2-custom-java-components-and-ajax-behaviors)

> An ajax listener, connected to your ajax event with the listener attribute, is a method that will be called every time the ajax request is made

which is exactly what i'm looking for.  i've also tried the first sample of code on that web page and it works as expected.
however, when i add the following code -

```
<h:commandButton id="d" image="#{CodeBean.imgSrc}"  action="#{CodeBean.clickImg()}">
      <f:ajax event="action" render="d"  listener="#{CodeBean.update}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

both 'clickImg' and 'update' functions are called (and 'clickImg' does its task), but the 'update' is being performed BEFORE the 'clickImg' (i've added to both function 'System.out.println(...)').  and yes - in that sample code the 'update' is being performed after the 'setHello'
that makes no sense to me - or did i miss something?
cheers,
eRez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fully by specification. Action listeners are called before actions during invoke action phase. If you need to execute a business action and/or to navigate, do it in `action`. If you need to listen on the action event so that you can if necessary do some preprocessing, use `listener`.

In your particular case, it look like you don't need the action listener at all. Just remove it and move the job into the `action` method. The `event` attribute is by the way superfluous. It already defaults to `action`. Just remove it. This works equally good:

```
<h:commandButton image="#{CodeBean.imgSrc}" action="#{CodeBean.clickImg}">
    <f:ajax render="@this" />
</h:commandButton>
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Answer (score 0):

in the example you looked at setHello was a setter of h:inputText value and not an action like in your code , that is what you missed... 
And that's why in the example the setter was called before the ajax listener...